# Is shared ownership of objects a sign of bad design?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, raii

**Background**: When reading [Dr. Stroustrup's papers](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs) and FAQs, I notice some strong "opinions" and great advices from legendary CS scientist and programmer. One of them is about `shared_ptr` in C++0x. He starts explaining about `shared_ptr` and how it represents shared ownership of the pointed object. At the last line, [he says and I quote](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-shared_ptr):

> . A `shared_ptr` represents shared
>   ownership but shared ownership isn't
>   my ideal: It is better if an object
>   has a definite owner and a definite,
>   predictable lifespan.

**My Question**: To what extent does RAII substitute other design patterns like Garbage Collection? I am assuming that manual memory management is not used to represent shared ownership in the system.

Comment: I think the quote is coming from the same direction as here: *"Please don't thoughtlessly replace pointers with shared_ptrs in an attempt to prevent memory leaks"* - don't use shared ownership unless neccessary. I highly doubt that Stroustrup doesn't see the value of managed shared ownership in systems of higher complexity.

Comment: @gf I agree with you that this is a design decision and there isn't any decision that is perfect 100% and I think Dr. Stroustrup meant the same thing. I would rephrase my question as "When does RAII fail"?

Comment: It is a *sign* of poor design.   But it is not *necessarily* poor design.   The horrific thing, to me, is that all modern scripting languages uses shared ownership *by default*.   It would be great if the next "node" or "python" to come along used "unique_ptr" style ownership by default.   Sure it would be harder to use... but probably more rewarding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> To what extent does RAII substitute other design patterns like Garbage Collection? I am assuming that manual memory management is not used to represent shared ownership in the system

Hmm, with GC, you don't really have to *think* about ownership. The object stays around as long as *anyone* needs it. Shared ownership is the default and the only choice.

And of course, everything *can* be done with shared ownership. But it sometimes leads to very clumsy code, because you **can't** control or limit the lifetime of an object. You have to use C#'s `using` blocks, or `try`/`finally` with close/dispose calls in the finally clause to ensure that the object gets cleaned up when it goes out of scope.

In those cases, RAII is a much better fit: When the object goes out of scope, all the cleanup should happen *automatically*.

RAII replaces GC to a large extent. 99% of the time, shared ownership isn't really what you *want* ideally. It is an acceptable compromise, in exchange for saving a lot of headaches by getting a garbage collector, but it doesn't really  match what you *want*. You *want* the resource to die at some point. Not before, and not after. When RAII is an option, it leads to more elegant, concise and robust code in those cases.

RAII is not perfect though. Mainly because it doesn't deal that well with the occasional case where you just **don't know** the lifetime of an object. It has to stay around for a long while, as long as anyone uses it. But you don't want to keep it around forever (or as long as the scope surrounding all the clients, which might just be the entirety of the main function).

In those cases, C++ users have to "downgrade" to shared ownership semantics, usually implemented by reference-counting through `shared_ptr`. And in that case, a GC wins out. It can implement shared ownership much more robustly (able to handle cycles, for example), and more efficiently (the amortized cost of ref counting is *huge* compared to a decent GC)

Ideally, I'd like to see both in a language. Most of the time, I want RAII, but occasionally, I have a resource I'd just like to throw into the air and not worry about when or where it's going to land, and just trust that it'll get cleaned up when it's safe to do so.

Comment: I'd like to have a reference or an explanation why ref-counting costs are "huge" compared to GC.

Comment: With ref-counting, every time a reference is created or destroyed, you need to update the ref counter (and it has to be done atomically, making it more expensive) . With a GC, you don't need to update a single byte of data in those cases, and instead, a garbage collection runs every once in a while, which traverses the currently live objects. The amortized cost of this is much smaller than the constant increment-decrement cycle of ref-counting.

Comment: Objects which can change while anyone is interested in them should generally have a discrete owner.  Objects which will not change while anyone is interested in them, but which will require cleanup afterward (e.g. immutable GDI objects) should ideally have shared ownership.  Immutable objects which do not require cleanup should be unowned (they should exist as long as they're needed, and evaporate when not).

Answer (score 8):

The job of a programmer is to express things elegantly in his language of choice.

C++ has very nice semantics for construction and destruction of objects on the stack. If a resource can be allocated for the duration of a scope block, then a good programmer will probably take that path of least resistance. The object's lifetime is delimited by braces which are probably already there anyway.

If there's no good way to put the object directly on the stack, maybe it can be put inside another object as a member. Now its lifetime is a little longer, but C++ still doe a lot automatically. The object's lifetime is delimited by a parent object — the problem has been delegated.

There might not be one parent, though. The next best thing is a sequence of adoptive parents. This is what `auto_ptr` is for. Still pretty good, because the programmer should know what particular parent is the owner. The object's lifetime is delimited by the lifetime of its sequence of owners. One step down the chain in determinism and per se elegance is `shared_ptr`: lifetime delimited by the union of a pool of owners.

But maybe this resource isn't concurrent with any other object, set of objects, or control flow in the system. It's created upon some event happening and destroyed upon another event. Although there are a lot of tools for delimiting lifetimes by delegations and other lifetimes, they aren't sufficient for computing any arbitrary function. So the programmer might decide to write a function of several variables to determine whether an object is coming into existence or disappearing, and call `new` and `delete`.

Finally, writing functions can be hard. Maybe the rules governing the object would take too much time and memory to actually compute! And it might just be really hard to express them elegantly, getting back to my original point. So for that we have garbage collection: the object lifetime is delimited by when you want it and when you don't.

---

Sorry for the rant, but I think the best way to answer your question is context: `shared_ptr` is just a tool for computing the lifetime of an object, which fits into a broad spectrum of alternatives. It works when it works. It should be used when it's elegant. It should not be used if you have less than a pool of owners, or if you're trying to compute some sophisticated function using it as a convoluted way to increment/decrement.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Your answer stressed some serious points. The main point for me is the "gap" in ownership you talked about. Why would it happen? Isn't my program supposed to know what it is doing with resources it "requested". I would appreciate an example where RAII fails compared to Garbage Collection.

Comment: GCC uses garbage collection because it's more elegant and probably more efficient than dedicating time and possibly memory to tracking the multitude of objects it uses. Garbage collection is also well-suited to scripting languages where the user might implement a memory leak.

Comment: @Potatoswatter GCC is written in C not in C++, so the example is ansering the wrong question :)

Comment: Are you asking for a product which was written in C++ using RAII and failed as a result? ;v) My belief outlined above is that the middle ground between RAII and GC is new/delete. Maybe I should generalize and say that compilers aren't very amenable to RAII. I am aware of one compiler that did use reference counting for everything, and it wasn't very successful, so there you go. It predated C++, though.

Comment: Should `auto_ptr` be `unique_ptr`, or are you old-school?

Comment: @Davislor This answer is from 2009.

Comment: Huh.  Old-school it is.  This question got pushed back to the top, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

> My Question: To what extent does RAII substitute other design patterns
>   like Garbage Collection? I am assuming that manual memory management
>   is not used to represent shared ownership in the system.

I'm not sure about calling this a design pattern, but in my equally strong opinion, and just talking about memory resources, RAII tackles almost all the problems that GC can solve while introducing fewer.

> Is shared ownership of objects a sign of bad design?

I share the thought that shared ownership is far, far from ideal in *most* cases, because the high-level design doesn't necessarily call for it. About the only time I've found it unavoidable is during the implementation of persistent data structures, where it's at least internalized as an implementation detail.

The biggest problem I find with GC or just shared ownership in general is that it doesn't free the developer of any responsibilities when it comes to application resources, but can give the illusion of doing so. If we have a case like this (`Scene` is the sole logical owner of the resource, but other things hold a reference/pointer to it like a camera storing a scene exclusion list defined by the user to omit from rendering):

[image]

And let's say the application resource is like an image, and its lifetime is tied to user input (ex: the image should be freed when the user requests to close a document containing it), then the work to properly free the resource is the same with or without GC.

Without GC, we might remove it from a scene list and allow its destructor to be invoked, while triggering an event to allow `Thing1`, `Thing2`, and `Thing3` to set their pointers to it to null or remove them from a list so that they don't have dangling pointers.

With GC, it's basically the same thing. We remove the resource from the scene list while triggering an event to allow `Thing1`, `Thing2`, and `Thing3` to set their references to null or remove them from a list so that the garbage collector can collect it.

**The Silent Programmer Mistake Which Flies Under Radar**

The difference in this scenario is what happens when a programmer mistake occurs, like `Thing2` failing to handle the removal event. If `Thing2` stores a pointer, it now has a dangling pointer and we might have a crash. That's catastrophic but something we might easily catch in our unit and integration tests, or at least something QA or testers will catch rather quickly. I don't work in a mission-critical or security-critical context, so if the crashy code managed to ship somehow, it's still not so bad if we can get a bug report, reproduce it, and detect it and fix it rather quickly.

If `Thing2` stores a strong reference and shares ownership, we have a very silent logical leak, and the image won't be freed until `Thing2` is destroyed (which it might not be destroyed until shutdown). In my domain, this silent nature of the mistake is very problematic, since it can go quietly unnoticed even after shipping until users start to notice that working in the application for an hour causes it to take gigabytes of memory, e.g., and starts slowing down until they restart it. And at that point, we might have accumulated a large number of these issues, since it's so easy for them to fly under the radar like a stealth fighter bug, and there's nothing I dislike more than stealth fighter bugs.

[image]

And it's due to that silent nature that I tend to dislike shared ownership with a passion, and TBH I never understood why GC is so popular (might be my particular domain -- I'm admittedly very ignorant of ones that are mission-critical, e.g.) to the point where I'm hungry for new languages *without GC*. I have found investigating all such leaks related to shared ownership to be very time-consuming, and sometimes investigating for hours only to find the leak was caused by source code outside of our control (third party plugin).

**Weak References**

Weak references are conceptually ideal to me for `Thing1`, `Thing2`, and `Thing3`. That would allow them to detect when the resource has been destroyed in hindsight without extending its lifetime, and perhaps we could guarantee a crash in those cases or some might even be able to gracefully deal with this in hindsight. The problem to me is that weak references are convertible to strong references and vice versa, so among the internal and third party developers out there, someone could still carelessly end up storing a strong reference in `Thing2` even though a weak reference would have been far more appropriate.

I did try in the past to encourage the use of weak references as much as possible among the internal team and documenting that it should be used in the SDK. Unfortunately it was difficult to promote the practice among such a wide and mixed group of people, and we still ended up with our share of logical leaks.

The ease at which anyone, at any given time, can extend the lifetime of an object far longer than appropriate by simply storing a strong reference to it in their object starts to become a very frightening prospect when looking down at a huge codebase that's leaking massive resources. I often wish that a very explicit syntax was required to store any kind of strong reference as a member of an object of a kind which at least would lead a developer to think twice about doing it needlessly.

**Explicit Destruction**

So I tend to favor explicit destruction for persistent application resources, like so:

```
on_removal_event:
    // This is ideal to me, not trying to release a bunch of strong
    // references and hoping things get implicitly destroyed.
    destroy(app_resource);
```

... since we can count on it to free the resource. We can't be completely assured that something out there in the system won't end up having a dangling pointer or weak reference, but at least those issues tend to be easy to detect and reproduce in testing. They don't go unnoticed for ages and accumulate.

The one tricky case has always been multithreading for me. In those cases, what I have found useful instead of full-blown garbage collection or, say, `shared_ptr`, is to simply defer destruction somehow:

```
on_removal_event:
    // *May* be deferred until threads are finished processing the resource.
    destroy(app_resource);
```

In some systems where the persistent threads are unified in a way such that they have a `processing` event, e.g., we can mark the resource to be destroyed in a deferred fashion in a time slice when threads are not being processed (almost starts to feel like stop-the-world GC, but we're keeping explicit destruction). In other cases, we might use, say, reference counting but in a way that avoids `shared_ptr`, where a resource's reference count starts at zero and will be destroyed using that explicit syntax above unless a thread locally extends its lifetime by incrementing the counter temporarily (ex: using a scoped resource in a local thread function).

As roundabout as that seems, it avoids exposing GC references or `shared_ptr` to the outside world which can easily tempt some developers (internally on your team or a third party developer) to store strong references (`shared_ptr`, e.g.) as a member of an object like `Thing2` and thereby extend a resource's lifetime inadvertently, and possibly for far, far longer than appropriate (possibly all the way until application shutdown).

**RAII**

Meanwhile RAII automatically eliminates physical leaks just as well as GC, but furthermore, it works for resources other than just memory. We can use it for a scoped mutex, a file which automatically closes on destruction, we can use it even to automatically reverse external side effects through scope guards, etc. etc.

So if given the choice and I had to pick one, it's easily RAII for me. I work in a domain where those silent memory leaks caused by shared ownership are absolutely killer, and a dangling pointer crash is actually preferable if (and it likely will) be caught early during testing. Even in some really obscure event that it's caught late, if it manifests itself in a crash close to the site where the mistake occurred, that's still preferable than using memory profiling tools and trying to figure out who forgot to release a reference while wading through millions of lines of code. In my very blunt opinion, GC introduces more problems than it solves for my particular domain (VFX, which is somewhat similar to games in terms of scene organization and application state), and one of the reasons besides those very silent shared ownership leaks is because it can give the developers the false impression that they don't have to think about resource management and ownership of persistent application resources while inadvertently causing logical leaks left and right.

> "When does RAII fail"

The only case I've ever encountered in my whole career where I couldn't think of any possible way to avoid shared ownership of some sort is when I implemented a library of persistent data structures, like so:

[image]

I used it to implement an immutable mesh data structure which can have portions modified without being made unique, like so (test with 4 million quadrangles):

[image]

Every single frame, a new mesh is being created as the user drags over it and sculpts it. The difference is that the new mesh is strong referencing parts not made unique by the brush so that we don't have to copy all the vertices, all the polygons, all the edges, etc. The immutable version trivializes thread safety, exception safety, non-destructive editing, undo systems, instancing, etc.

In this case the whole concept of the immutable data structure revolves around shared ownership to avoid duplicating data that wasn't made unique. It's a genuine case where we cannot avoid shared ownership no matter what (at least I can't think of any possible way).

That's about the only case where we might need GC or reference counting that I've encountered. Others might have encountered some of their own, but from my experience, very, very few cases genuinely need shared ownership at the design level.

Answer (score 3):

Is Garbage Collection a Design Pattern? I don't know.

The big advantage of shared ownership, is its inherent predictability. With GC the reclamation of resources is out of your hands. Thats the point. When, and how it happens is usually not on the mind of the developer using it. With shared ownership, you are in control (beware, sometimes too much control is a bad thing). Lets say your app spawns off a million shared_ptr's to X. All of those are your doing, you are responsible for them and you have total control over when those references are created and destroyed. So a determined and careful programmer should know exaclty who references what and for how long. If you want an object to be destroyed, you have to destroy all the shared references to it, and viola, it's gone.

This carries some profound consequences for people who make realtime software, which MUST be totally predictable. This also means you can fudge up in ways that look an awful lot like memory leaks. I personally don't want to be a determined and careful programmer when I don't have to be (go ahead and laugh, I want to go on picnics and bike rides, not count my references), so where appropriate GC is my prefered route. I have written a little bit of realtime sound software, and used shared references to manage resources predictably.

Your question: When does RAII fail? (In the context of shared references)
My Answer: When you can't answer the question: who may have a reference to this? When vicious insipid circles of ownership develop.

My question: When does GC fail?
My answer: When you want total control and predictability. When the GC is the written by Sun Microsystems in a last minute dash to deadline and has ridiculous behaviors which could only have been designed and implemented by severely drunk protohuman code monkeys borrowed from Microsoft.

My opinion: I think BS is just really serious about clear design. It seems obvious that having one place where resources are destroyed is usually a clearer design than having many places where they might destroyed.